# How to specify tikzpicture vertical position in the middle of text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I would like to put a tikzpicture in the middle of a text line, but I can't find how to specify vertical positionning. Explications :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (2.25, 2) -- (2,0);
 \draw (.7, 0) -- (4,0) -- (2.25, 2) node[right] {$A_i$} -- (.7,0);
 \draw (3,0) -- (2.125, 1) node[right] {$A_j$} -- (1.4,0);
 \draw (1.05, 0) node[below] {$v$} (2,0) node[below] {$w$} (3.5, 0) node[below] {$x$} (4.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives me something like

[image: this alignment]

but I would like to get something like

[image: this other alignment]

I know vertical positioning options exist for tabular and array (`\begin{array}[b]{rcl}` for a bottom alignment for exemple), but I can't find something similar for tikzpictures.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach that works if you want to put more text on the same line. It puts the figure in a box and then lowers the box by half its height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\mybox
\def\centerfigure#1{%
    \setbox\mybox\hbox{#1}%
    \raisebox{-0.5\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}{\copy\mybox}%
}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\centerfigure{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (2.25, 2) -- (2,0);
 \draw (.7, 0) -- (4,0) -- (2.25, 2) node[right] {$A_i$} -- (.7,0);
 \draw (3,0) -- (2.125, 1) node[right] {$A_j$} -- (1.4,0);
 \draw (1.05, 0) node[below] {$v$} (2,0) node[below] {$w$} (3.5, 0) node[below] {$x$} (4.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}} more text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Coincidentally, I just solved a similar problem. Applied to your example, that works out to be this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(AA.base)]%
 \draw (2.25, 2) -- (2,0);
 \draw (.7, 0) -- (4,0) -- (2.25, 2) node[right] {$A_i$} -- (.7,0);
 \draw (3,0) -- (2.125, 1) node[right](AA) {$A_j$} -- (1.4,0);
 \draw (1.05, 0) node[below] {$v$} (2,0) node[below] {$w$} (3.5, 0) node[below] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
more text
\end{document}
```

[image: Centering tikz figure on baseline.]

True, that this works happens to be due to the nature of the figure. Admittedly, Hood Chatham's solution is more general.

Changing `[baseline=(AA.base)]` to `[baseline=(AA.south)]` produces this:

[image: Alternate version]

Answer (score 2):

I think using math mode and `\vcenter` is the way to go for vertically centering stuff on the current text line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
$\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (2.25, 2) -- (2,0);
 \draw (.7, 0) -- (4,0) -- (2.25, 2) node[right] {$A_i$} -- (.7,0);
 \draw (3,0) -- (2.125, 1) node[right] {$A_j$} -- (1.4,0);
 \draw (1.05, 0) node[below] {$v$} (2,0) node[below] {$w$} (3.5, 0) node[below] {$x$} (4.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but the `\vcenter` environment ends the line, so I can't continue the line with some text.

Comment: That's annoying. I'll see if I can fix that...

Comment: See my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified [sgmoye](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397403/235505) solution to be more general. Seems to work perfectly but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box)]
 \draw (2.25, 2) -- (2,0);
 \draw (.7, 0) -- (4,0) -- (2.25, 2) node[right] {$A_i$} -- (.7,0);
 \draw (3,0) -- (2.125, 1) node[right] {$A_j$} -- (1.4,0);
 \draw (1.05, 0) node[below] {$v$} (2,0) node[below] {$w$} (3.5, 0) node[below] {$x$} (4.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered latex document]

Note that you can also use `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` to position the figure right below the text.

I've found this solution in [pgf manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#subsubsection.12.2.1).

Comment: This is IMHO the best solution.